# Element Isn't Cloning ..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on a basic commment script. This basically means whatever you type into the textboxes (one for title, and another for message) and then press submit, your comment should be added to the page, similarly how youtube does it. I was planning on having a prebuilt HTML div, and just clone it for every new comment that is made (and of course changing the text to match). The problem is that I can not get my script to work. **When you press submit, no element is cloned into the container. This is my issue**. What is the problem?

EDIT: I updated the code and the new error is (`Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`)

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const template = document.comment;
  const form = document.forms.comment;
  const container = document.querySelector('.container')
  form.submit2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const name = form.name;
    const text = form.text;
    const newNode = template.cloneNode(true);
    newNode.classList.remove('hidden')
    container.appendChild(newNode)
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.comment-form input {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = 'style.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form name = "comment" class = "comm">
        <input type = "text" maxlength = 20 name = 'name' placeholder = 'name'>
        <textarea name = "text" placeholder = 'comment'></textarea>
        <input type = "button" value = "submit" name = "submit2">
      </form>
      <div name = "comment" class = 'hidden'>
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "container"></div>
      <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `form.submit` <= Don't name elements inside a form `submit`.  Submit is a method on the form.  This is an old issue that crops up now and then.  You should always name it something else to avoid conflicting with the properties and inadvertently replacing the native method on the element.

Comment: Also `name` and `text` are not children of the submit button.

Comment: @Taplar Good point. I fixed that issue and named it `submit2`. The thing is, the script still does not work

Comment: Did you see my second comment?

Comment: @Taplar `name` and `text` aren't children of the submit button. That explains alot. The error is now `container.appendChild` is not a  function. This is probally something that can be fixed

Comment: you are using `getElementsByClassName` which return array-like ... add `[0]` at the end of your declration line or use `querySelector`

Comment: @AymanMorsy I added a query selector and the script still is not budging

Comment: const container = document.querySelector("div .container");

Comment: can you check what you have in `container` by logging it when event fire ?

Comment: @AymanMorsy null

Comment: your form submit reload  the original page, and the cloned element go to the garbage

Comment: @MisterJojo `type="button"`

Comment: when using querySelector write selector like css `('.container')` ` not `('container')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
  const template = document.querySelector('.comment-template');
  const form = document.querySelector('.comment-form');
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');

  form.querySelector('.submit-button').addEventListener('click', e => {
    const newNode = template.cloneNode(true);

    newNode.querySelector('.name').innerText =
        form.querySelector('.name').value;
    newNode.querySelector('.comment').innerText =
        form.querySelector('.comment').value;

    newNode.classList.remove('hidden');
    container.appendChild(newNode);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.comment-form input {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form class="comment-form">
  <input type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="name" class="name">
  <textarea name="text" placeholder="comment" class="comment"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="submit" class="submit-button">
</form>

<div class="comment-template hidden">
  <h1 class="name"></h1>
  <p class="comment"></p>
</div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

I changed the logic to use `querySelector` instead of the name access.  Also fixed that the container was originally coming back as an array like object, instead of just one element, which is why the append child didn't work.  Also added the logic to actually stick the name and comment text into the cloned node.

Comment: `'Also fixed that the container was originally coming back as an array like object, instead of just one element, which is why the append child didn't work.'`
This isn't true because even after I changed it it didn't work

Comment: You kind of changed all the variables, tags, etc so it is a little hard to see the changes here

Comment: Can you also explain why you used `addEventListener` with an `e` parameter when you don't even use the `e`? Can you also explain why you used addEventlistener instead of just `window.onload`? There is no difference in the script

Comment: Actually, can you only tell me what to change to my code to make it work and not rewrite the full thing?

Comment: `const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')` <= `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object.  This is reinforced by the method name being "getElements".  The usage of `addEventListener` is there in order to add actual event listeners, rather than setting the event properties on the object, which have limitations.  The usage of the `e` passed in is simply part of my programming style, and could be replaced with `()` or `_` or whatever you prefer more.

Comment: Even after I changed `document.getElementsByClassName('container')` to ` document.querySelector("div .container")` it still didn't work, which dosen't make any sense

Comment: Can you tell me what to change to my code to make it work?  I don't like the idea of my script getting entirely rewritten because then I am not learning anything. I want to know **why** my script wasn't functioning and how to fix it

Comment: Then please update your original question with your modified code so we can see what you are working with now.

Comment: If you have more questions about this answer, please ask.  If you do not find it helpful, then feel free to downvote.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, your answer is fine, it is just that you rewritten the entire script. I want to know why my code wasn't working, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let template = document.comment;
  // You have two elements with a name of comment.  It is being set as the
  // form, and not the div that presumably you are trying to clone later.
  console.log("My template", template);
  
  // so to fix that, you can select the element by its class instead
  template = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];
  console.log("My fixed template", template);
  
  const form = document.forms.comment;
  console.log("My form", form);
  
  // getElementsByClassName returns an array like object, even if there
  // is only one element matched.  Using [0] lets us get just a single one
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
  console.log("My container", container);
  
  // using the name change you said you made to have the button named
  // submit2 instead of submit, we can bind the click event to it
  console.log("My submit button", form.submit2);
  
  form.submit2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let name = form.submit2.name;
    console.log("My name", name);
    
    // The "name" element is not a child of the submit button.  It is a
    // sibling element with it's own name
    // We need to reference it instead, and grab the value
    name = form.name.value;
    console.log("My fixed name", name);
    
    let text = form.submit2.text;
    console.log("My text", text);
    
    // Same issue with the text
    text = form.text.value;
    console.log("My fixed text", text);
    
    const newNode = template.cloneNode(true);
    console.log("My new node", newNode.outerHTML);
    
    // As you can see, you cloned the node, but you haven't put the name
    // or text on it.  Need to do that before appending it to the DOM.
    newNode.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = name;
    newNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = text;
    
    console.log("My fixed new node", newNode.outerHTML);
    
    newNode.classList.remove('hidden');
    container.appendChild(newNode);
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.comm input{
  display: block;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = 'style.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form name = "comment" class = "comm">
        <input type = "text" maxlength = 20 name = 'name' placeholder = 'name'>
        <textarea name = "text" placeholder = 'comment'></textarea>
        <input type = "button" value = "submit" name = "submit2">
      </form>
      <div name = "comment" class = 'hidden'>
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "container"></div>
      <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Providing an alternative answer that steps through the original logic, attempting to show the issues, and show how to fix them.  Trying to stay as close to the original logic as possible.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that in my HTML elements I added whitespace. Never add spaces around the `=` sign. Nothing was wrong with the script itself.